# Reset response to null after search input is cleared Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, conditional-rendering

How do I reset a my response to NULL, as it is in my data upon the clearing/deleting of the query in my search bar?

I've vaguely achieved this with v-show and a query length, but I know its not really correct because it's hiding the results, not actually clearing them from the DOM. I also tried tying an ELSE statement to the query method with no luck.

```
<div class="searchBarContainer">
   <div class="search">
      <div class="searchBar">
       <form v-on:submit="queryGitHub(query)">
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search Repositories Ex. Hello 
 World" v-model="query" />
      <button type="submit" v-on:click="isHidden = 
 !isHidden">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="results" id="results" v-if="response" v-show="query.length = 
 0">
    <div class="notFound" v-if="response.length == 0">
      <p>Sorry buddy, try another search!</p>
    </div>

    <div class="resultsHeadings" v-if="response.length >= 1">
      <p>Name</p>
      <p>Language</p>
    </div>

    <div class="items" v-if="response.length >= 1">
      <div class="item" v-for="(item, index) in response, filteredList" 
 v-bind:id="item.id" :key="index"> 
          <p>{{item.name}}</p>
          <p>{{item.language}}</p>

          <div class="expand">
            <a @click="pushItem(index)">
              <div class="itemButton">
                <button v-on:click="addFave(item.id, item.forks)">Add to 
 Favorites</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>


 <script>

 export default{
  data () {
    return {
     query:'',
     response: null,
     items: [],
     faves: [],
     activeItems: [],
   }
  },
  methods: {
    queryGitHub(q) {
    if (q.length >= 1){
    fetch('https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=' + q)
    .then((j) => {
      return j.json();
    })
    .then ((r) => {
    console.log(r);
    //this.response = r.items;

    this.response = r.items.slice(0, 15)
      })
    }
    }
    }
  };
```

I need my search input to remove the response by resetting it to NULL once the input has been cleared by the visitor.  Presently if you clear the input, the results disappear which is great but if you type again, the results just reappear. So they are hidden, not removed. I believe I need a function, possibly via computed, to set the response in data back to null upon the clearing of the input.

Comment: Not sure what is the behaviour you are trying to reach here, do you mean that when the user delete the search input, your `response` is set to `null` again ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could attach an `input` event handler to your `input` element and inside it you'll check the length of the `query` string. If it's zero, then set `response` to `null`.

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Search Repositories Ex. Hello 
 World" v-model="query" @input="onQueryChange" />
```

The `onQueryChange` function should be under `methods` instead of `computed` since it's not returning any derived data.

```
methods: {
  onQueryChange(event) {

    // can be this.query.length === 0 as well
    if(event.target.value.trim().length === 0) {
      this.response = null;
    }

  }
}
```